# Custom drupal module does not appear on the extend page

Tags: composer

I have created a custom module, yet it does not appear on the extend page.
I have my_new_block.info.yml file in modules/custom/my_new_block/:

```
name: My New Block
description: Create own blocks.
package: Garage


type: module
core: 8.x

dependencies:
  - block
```

In addition, when I try to install any drupal module with composer, it also is not recognised in the extend page. 
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a preceding issue with installation, I had several drupal projects under Projects folder, the newer project tried to access modules in the directory of the older one. Probably, the paths have somehow mixed, leading to the problems with modules installation and database connection(it was not described in a settings.php file). After the disabling of the previous projects and reinstallation of the current one, everything has been working properly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this example [Hello World Module](https://github.com/sidharrell/D8HWexample) and then change it for your case and do not forget to delete a Drupal cache.